# TwitterAPIExchange PHP Xampp SSL certification issue

Tags: php, ssl, curl, xampp

I am running my PHP application on Xamp,as I write the following code:

```
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();
```

it starts giving the following exceptions

> **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\TwitterAPIExchange.php:315 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\twitterapp.php(23):
>   TwitterAPIExchange->performRequest() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 315**

I have tried all the solutions present on stack overflow and on the internet but non have them helps solving my problem

I have also added these lines

```
curl.cainfo=”C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem”
openssl.cafile=”C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem”
```

in php.ini files(both development and production) at the end of these files

I also removed **;** from [extension=php_curl.dll]in php.ini files(both development and production)

what more I should do to solve this problem

Comment: `all the solutions present [...] on the internet` o.o

Comment: Related: There are three PHP config files. The one you want it just called `php.ini`. You can find it here: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.

Comment: Also, seeing as PHP is loaded as a module in Apache, you need to restart Apache in your XAMPP control panel before the changes will take effect.

Comment: If PHP/cURL is really using the CA file indicated, then this file is probably outdated and is missing the CA certificate Twitter is using.  maybe try this one: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/cacert.pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you're editing `php.ini`, and not `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production`. From what I understand, these extra files are some sort of "template" for easy modification of the default `php.ini` file. You can find it (XAMPP default installation) at `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.

Also, as you're running Apache, be sure to restart it to make sure that your changes to the config file take effect.

If you're in doubt, you can always use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) at the start of your script to over-ride the settings at runtime.

Comment: @ashnashamim Updated answer.

Comment: I did the changes but still it is giving the same issue

Comment: @ashnashamim Did you restart Apache? (Note: The service, not the XAMPP control panel itself.)

Comment: @ashnashamim I wouldn't know, I don't use Twitter's API, but the exception certainly doesn't allude to that.

Comment: Thanks your answer helps solving this problem :)